# How do I extract a list of Objects from a java stream?

Tags: java-8

Note that there are 3 levels of nesting here - 
I am trying to retrieve a list of filters from a filtersubgroup list which is in a filtersupergroup list.
the filter has a property - fieldname.
I managed to extract the list of field names from the data structure using the following method :

```
public static List<String> extractFilterFieldsAsAList(QuerySearchRequestDTO requestDTO) {
    return requestDTO.getFilter().parallelStream()
            .map(new Function<FilterSuperGroup, String>() {
                @Override
                public String  apply(FilterSuperGroup filterSuperGroup) {

                    return filterSuperGroup.getFilterSubGroup().parallelStream()
                            .map(new Function<FilterSubGroup, String>() {
                                @Override
                                public String apply(FilterSubGroup filterSubGroup) {

                                    return filterSubGroup.getFilter().parallelStream()
                                            .map(new Function<Filter, String>() {

                                                @Override
                                                public String apply(Filter t) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                    return t.getFieldName();
                                                }

                                            }).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
                                }

                            }).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
                }
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Question: However, in another scenario (BELOW) I need a List as the output. 
I want to replace findAny().get() with something that doesn't break the stream nesting. findAny().get() is obviously incorrect as it returns only one element from each nest. How do I fix this?

```
public static List<Filter> prepareFilterListFromRequest(QuerySearchRequestDTO requestDTO) {
    List<Filter> listToReturn = new ArrayList<>();

    listToReturn.addAll(requestDTO.getFilter().stream()
            .map(new Function<FilterSuperGroup, List<Filter>>() {

                @Override
                public List<Filter> apply(FilterSuperGroup filterSuperGroup) {
                    return filterSuperGroup.getFilterSubGroup().parallelStream()
                            .map(new Function<FilterSubGroup, Filter>() {

                                @Override
                                public Filter apply(FilterSubGroup filterSubGroup) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    return  filterSubGroup.getFilter().stream()
                                            .map(new Function<Filter, Filter>() {

                                                @Override
                                                public Filter apply(Filter t) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                    return t;
                                                }

                                            }).findAny().get();
                                }
                            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
                }
            }).findAny().get()
            );


    return listToReturn;
}
```

Comment: Using this as of now:
https://pastebin.com/raw/iEd9vGwM

Comment: Please, replace all these anonymous inner classes with lambda expressions. Making such code readable is exactly the reason they have been added to the language. Then, we have a chance to recognize what the code is doing…